# PC randomly shutsdown with a kernel power (id 41) critical error

Tags: windows, windows-11, crash, power

I've been having problems lately with my PC randomly restarting itself regardless of the current stress it's facing.

I've been monitoring the temperature of my cpu with Core Temp and I haven't seen anything out of the ordinary.

Revising the event viewer, I've found the critical error that happens at the time of the shutdown:

Crítico 19/08/2023 19:34:30 Kernel-Power    41  (63)

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power" Guid="{331c3b3a-2005-44c2-ac5e-77220c37d6b4}" /> 
  <EventID>41</EventID> 
  <Version>9</Version> 
  <Level>1</Level> 
  <Task>63</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x8000400000000002</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2023-08-19T17:34:30.2851144Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>40857</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="4" ThreadID="8" /> 
  <Channel>System</Channel> 
  <Computer>DESKTOP-R7JOPM3</Computer> 
  <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data Name="BugcheckCode">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="BugcheckParameter1">0x0</Data> 
  <Data Name="BugcheckParameter2">0x0</Data> 
  <Data Name="BugcheckParameter3">0x0</Data> 
  <Data Name="BugcheckParameter4">0x0</Data> 
  <Data Name="SleepInProgress">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="PowerButtonTimestamp">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="BootAppStatus">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="Checkpoint">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="ConnectedStandbyInProgress">false</Data> 
  <Data Name="SystemSleepTransitionsToOn">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="CsEntryScenarioInstanceId">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="BugcheckInfoFromEFI">false</Data> 
  <Data Name="CheckpointStatus">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="CsEntryScenarioInstanceIdV2">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="LongPowerButtonPressDetected">false</Data> 
  <Data Name="LidReliability">false</Data> 
  <Data Name="InputSuppressionState">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="PowerButtonSuppressionState">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="LidState">3</Data> 
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Right before this one, there is always this info event:

Información 19/08/2023 19:34:30 Kernel-Power    125 (86)

```
 <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power" Guid="{331c3b3a-2005-44c2-ac5e-77220c37d6b4}" /> 
  <EventID>125</EventID> 
  <Version>4</Version> 
  <Level>4</Level> 
  <Task>86</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x8000000000000020</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2023-08-19T17:34:30.2759392Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>40856</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="4" ThreadID="8" /> 
  <Channel>System</Channel> 
  <Computer>DESKTOP-R7JOPM3</Computer> 
  <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data Name="ThermalZoneDeviceInstanceLength">9</Data> 
  <Data Name="ThermalZoneDeviceInstance">\_TZ.TZ00</Data> 
  <Data Name="_PSV">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="_TC1">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="_TC2">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="_TSP">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="_AC0">353</Data> 
  <Data Name="_AC1">328</Data> 
  <Data Name="_AC2">323</Data> 
  <Data Name="_AC3">318</Data> 
  <Data Name="_AC4">313</Data> 
  <Data Name="_AC5">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="_AC6">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="_AC7">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="_AC8">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="_AC9">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="_CRT">378</Data> 
  <Data Name="_HOT">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="MinimumThrottle">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="_CR3">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="OverThrottleThreshold">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="DescriptionLength">0</Data> 
  <Data Name="Description" /> 
  <Data Name="_TZP">0</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

There is nothing of value in my memory.dmp file, last time it was updated was over a week ago so it seems it didn't catch any error.

Any idea on what the issue might be?

Bonus info dump that it's probably not related but just in case it helps: The pc is kinda new, I replaced everything except the main ssd about a year ago. I checked the health of both ssd's and it's over 95%. I also did a memory checkup and everything shows ok. The fans don't stop moving at any point and the temp of the cpu seems fine. The pc shuts down even if there are not apps running (I had it shut down while being on the desktop).

You can find my DxDiag file here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WnMbZN32cLq94dufoVrNDB1EdIU8iq-l/view?usp=drive_link

Comment: What is the make and model of the computer's power supply? Are you sure that the power lead is securely connected into it?

Comment: And Microsoft have some other things to check for in [Scenario 3: The computer is unresponsive or randomly restarts, and Event ID 41 isn't recorded or the Event ID 41 entry or lists error code values of zero](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/performance/event-id-41-restart#scenario-3-the-computer-is-unresponsive-or-randomly-restarts-and-event-id-41-isnt-recorded-or-the-event-id-41-entry-or-lists-error-code-values-of-zero).

Comment: @AndrewMorton Hi, my psu is this one: https://www.amazon.es/gp/product/B07W7YD7D1/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o02_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1
Seasonic Platinum 650W

The power lead seems to be connected properly, yes.